# Generic constraint with any type

Tags: typescript

I have to start showing my code in order to explain my problem.

**My generic classes:**

```
export class RpcPublisherMessage<T extends RpcPublisherRequest<T>> {
  constructor(public publisherRequest: T, public publishOptions: Options.Publish = {}, public timeoutMs?: number) {}
}

export class RpcPublisherRequest<T> extends RpcMessageData<T> {
  constructor(payload: T, private context: string) {
    super(payload);
  }

  public toBuffer(): Buffer {
    return Buffer.from(...);
  }
}
```

**My problem:**

```
  public async dispatchMessage(rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<any>): Promise<IRequestMessageResponse> {
    const message = rpcMessage.publisherRequest; // I can not call toBuffer() here
  }
```

This is where I want to use an instance of `RpcPublisherMessage<any>`. Since the RpcPublishermessage has a generic constraint I expected that I am able to call `toBuffer()` on the publisherRequest property, but apparently I am not.

**What I tried to fix that:**

I thought it's maybe because of the any in `RpcPublisherMessage<any>` which maybe also needs the constraint given, but something like `rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<any extends RpcPublisherRequest<any>>` in the function parameters hasn't worked. VSCode then says

> [ts] Parameter 'rpcMessage' of public method from exported class has
>   or is using private name ''.

**My question:**

Why am I not able to call `toBuffer()` on `publisherRequest`even though I specified a constraint for this property?

Comment: What do you mean "apparently I am not"?  You gave it an `any` type, so you can call anything you want on it.  What error are you seeing?  Or are you interpreting lack of IntelliSense hinting as meaning you can't call it?

Comment: `class RpcPublisherMessage<T extends RpcPublisherRequest<T>>` is unlikely to do what you want; do you really mean that you want `T` to be an `RpcPublisherRequest` with *itself* as the payload type?  Probably you just mean `T extends RpcPublisherRequest<any>` or something.

Comment: The fix to your problem might be `rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<RpcPublisherRequest<any>>`, so IntelliSense will hint you about `toBuffer()`.

Comment: I'm happy to write these up as an answer but I'm confused enough about your question to not be sure if it is what you're asking for.

Comment: @jcalz I want T to be an instance which inherits from RpcPublisherRequest. I know that sounds really weird, but I am still elloborating this approach to see if I can simplify the code design at a later point. And yes your third comment has actually fixed it the way I wanted it and it makes sense to me. I'd be happy to mark it as the right answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating my comments as an answer.

---

Aside: the following definition

```
export class RpcPublisherMessage<T extends RpcPublisherRequest<T>> { ... }
```

isn't what you want to say.  Literally, you're saying that the parameter `T` should be assignable to `RpcPublisherRequest<T>`, where that second `T` *is the same `T` as the first*.  Unless you want the `payload` of the `RpcPublisherRequest` to be an `RpcPublisherMessage` whose `publisherRequest` type is a `RpcPublisherRequest` whose `payload` is an `RpcPublisherMessage` whose `publisherRequest` is a ...  :shudders:  Unless you actually want a recursive type bound for `T`, you should change that definition.

If all you want is that `T` should be an `RpcPublisherRequest<U>` for *some* `U`, then you can get away with doing this:

```
export class RpcPublisherMessage<T extends RpcPublisherRequest<any>> { ... }
```

This is no longer a recursive type bound.

---

Main: the problem you have with this

```
public async dispatchMessage(
  rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<any>
): Promise<IRequestMessageResponse> {
  const message = rpcMessage.publisherRequest.toBuffer(); // no error
  const massage = rpcMessage.publisherRequest.toButter(); // also no error
}
```

should not be that you *can't* call `toBuffer()`.  Rather, the problem is that `rpcMessage.publisherRequest` is typed as `any`, which means you can call `toBuffer()` without complaint.  But you can also call `toButter()` it without complaint, which is bad.  And you get no IntelliSense suggesting methods since an `any` type can have any properties whatsoever, which is bad.

And this is because `RpcPublisherMessage<any>` specifies that `T` is `any`, which meets all constraints but doesn't give you any type hinting.  If you want a tighter constraint, you can specify `T` to be `RpcPublisherRequest<any>` instead:

```
public async dispatchMessage(
  rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<RpcPublisherRequest<any>>
): Promise<IRequestMessageResponse> {
  const message = rpcMessage.publisherRequest.toBuffer(); // no error
  const massage = rpcMessage.publisherRequest.toButter(); // error, yay!
}
```

That should fix your issues.  If you need to keep track of the particular payload type of the request type, you could always make `dispatchMessage()` a generic method like this:

```
public async dispatchMessage<P>(
  rpcMessage: RpcPublisherMessage<RpcPublisherRequest<P>>
): Promise<IRequestMessageResponse> {
  const message = rpcMessage.publisherRequest.toBuffer(); // no error
}
```

where the `P` is your generic payload type.  But you might not need to go that far.

---

Okay hope that helps; good luck!